# Android-Facebook SDK: Unable to share photo, dialog not showing

Tags: android, android-facebook

This is my first time using the Android-Facebook SDK. I am trying to post a bitmap but I keep on getting this message:

```
Warning: Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to copy image.
```

I am able to post simple links, but not the ones with photos.

How should I fix this? Also, one thing I noticed is that the StatusCallback.call() is not being called.

```
public abstract class FacebookReadyBaseActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "FacebookReadyBaseActivity";

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    protected PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
    private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";
    protected boolean canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos;
    private boolean canPresentShareDialog;
    private GraphUser user;
    private GraphPlace place;
    private List<GraphUser> tags;
    protected Bitmap pendingBitmap;

    protected enum PendingAction {
        NONE, POST_PHOTO, POST_STATUS_UPDATE
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        canPresentShareDialog = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this,
                FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG);
        canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(
                this, FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.PHOTOS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data,
                new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall,
                            Exception error, Bundle data) {
                        Log.e(TAG, String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(
                            FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Success!");
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    protected UiLifecycleHelper getFacebookUiHelper() {
        return uiHelper;
    }

    protected void performPublish(PendingAction action, boolean allowNoSession) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            pendingAction = action;
            if (hasPublishPermission()) {
                // We can do the action right away.
                handlePendingAction();
                return;
            } else if (session.isOpened()) {
                // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when
                // we get called back.
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        this, PERMISSION));
                return;
            }
        }

        if (allowNoSession) {
            pendingAction = action;
            handlePendingAction();
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return session != null
                && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
    private void handlePendingAction() {
        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but
        // we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

        switch (previouslyPendingAction) {
        case POST_PHOTO:
            postPhoto();
            break;
        case POST_STATUS_UPDATE:
            postStatusUpdate();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void postPhoto() {

        if (canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForPhoto(
                    pendingBitmap).build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), pendingBitmap,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            InfoDialog.newInstance(
                                    FacebookReadyBaseActivity.this, "Done",
                                    "Photo share finished.", null).show();
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
        }
    }

    private void postStatusUpdate() {
        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForLink()
                    .build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            // TODO fixme
            final String message = "Status update finished.";
            Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), message, place, tags,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                            InfoDialog.newInstance(
                                    FacebookReadyBaseActivity.this, "Done",
                                    message, null).show();
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();

        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }

    private FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilderForPhoto(
            Bitmap... photos) {
        return new FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .addPhotos(Arrays.asList(photos));
    }

    private FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilderForLink() {
        return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setName("Hello Facebook")
                .setDescription(
                        "The 'Hello Facebook' sample application showcases simple Facebook integration")
                .setLink("http://developers.facebook.com/android");
    }


    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE
                && (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException || exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
            InfoDialog.newInstance(FacebookReadyBaseActivity.this, "Failed",
                    "Not granted.", null).show();
            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
        } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
            handlePendingAction();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your activity code.

Comment: @mussharapp bitmap posting sucess in facebook

Comment: @Mark, do you have to put the callback inside of `onActivityResult()`? I'm trying to follow the Facebook guide for posting photos but it's not clear, and it doesn't say anything about adding code there. But I followed their guide and my dialog does not show. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally got it to work!

In the provided HelloFacebookSample project I saw this in the manifest:

```
 <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider355198514515820"
                  android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"
                  android:exported="true"/>
```

I simply changed the number part using my own Facebook application ID. Not sure why I didn't see this in the documentation.

**EDIT**
Found this afterwards: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/NativeAppCallContentProvider/

Comment: I am Using the HelloFacebookSample project when facebookapp installed in mydeveice  its works fine for me.fbapp not installed bitmap not posting

Comment: The current documentation (as of June 2015) says to use this: `<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />`, where you put your app ID in the place of `{APP_ID}`, but I had that all along and still getting the same error. :(